# Curiously recurring template pattern and call operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am playing with the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern and call operator overload and I am facing a compilation error I can't explain. I defined the following classes:

```
template<class DERIVED>
struct Base
{
    void operator() (int n) const {}
    void foo        (int n) const {}
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void operator() (int n, int m) const {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived  x;
    
    x (1,2);                            // ok
    x (1);                              // ko -> does not compile
    static_cast<Base<Derived>>(x) (1);  // ok
    x.foo(1);                           // ok
}
```

I can instantiate `x` and the compiler is happy with the operator defined in `Derived` but not with the one defined in `Base`; I have to force a static_cast on the `Base` class in order to make the one arg operator work. On the other hand, there is no issue when calling `foo`.

**Why the one arg overload is not directly usable on a `Derived` instance ?**

Comment: you can't overload a function from a base class, any overloads hide the base class function: https://godbolt.org/z/x9TG96h3r

Answer (score 2):

`operator()` in `Derived` is hiding the operator in the base class. If you want to be able to call the base class `operator()`, bring it into `Derived` with `using`:

```cpp
struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    using Base<Derived>::operator();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8vz4o6WE6)